# Is it safe to use surge protector with 12vDC mobile power inverter?

Tags: inverter

Is it safe to use a surge protector which is plugged into a 12VDC mobile power inverter? Or will it damage the surge protector (or the inverter)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on their implementation.

If inverter gives you sine output(unlikely, at least for mid-range models) - you should be fine.
If inverter give you rectangle output - there is some possibility of damaging protector.

I would turn it on and see if they overheat. If it's not the case - you should be fine.

Comment: You just described the entirety of my debugging process:  Plug it in, if it burns up - something is wrong!

Comment: just try not to go over the Power rating of the inverter. you should have a tag saying how many watts its rated for. But dont worry if it gets slightly hot(can still touch it and not get burned)

Comment: @RQDQ: Well, not burnup, but heating above 50C :-)

Answer (score 0):

rms voltage of a square wave inverter is 120 but the true voltage is 172 from what i remember this will cause a mov to partly short as they are designed to do so at 150 volts

in simple terms a square wave inverter has on and off vs a sine wave that goes up slowly and back down it averages out should not really say average as route means square can vary slightly from a true average if you want a light bulb to light up at the same brightness or a transformer to be able to provide step down voltage your fine you want to work a switching power supply not rated for 100-240 your gonna fry it

if say a laptop power supply says its rated for 100-240 your fine if it said 120, 125 or 110 it will likely fry with a with a 120 rms square wave the exact why i will not get into that would require an engineering degree but in simple terms it will charge up a capacitor that is expecting 120 and expose sensitive parts designed for 120 to 172 as the capacitor will be charging up to the peek voltage not the rms

while rectifying aka converting ac into dc then filtering it with a cap say from a 12 ac source rms with out the cap would be 12 volts put the cap on and it will jump to 17 volts put a load on it and it will drop this from ripple voltage hike can be reduced with an inductor but it will still be there and you will still have what is known as ripple voltage the most common way to deal with this when space is not an issue is a large capacitor this would help your inverter out by reducing surges on its dc side a cap made for large car audio this may or may not clean up the output of your inverter you would need an oscilloscope to know for sure but it would not hurt i would personally add a cap if its a large inverter with heavy loads like motors or even a computer simply put if the power is not there a surge of current can not be taken if not present the lack of this capacity can put extra strain on your inverter as it will have to provide higher outputs for longer periods of time if the input voltage drops causing the output voltage to stop causing loads to take longer to initialize

Comment: It's probably worth adding some capital letters to this answer and looking at the structure, at the moment it's hard to read.

Comment: Please capitalize your sentences as well as [the first-person pronoun, I](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/7986). Also add the v designator for numbers that refer to volts.

Comment: The peak voltage of a 120v rms sine wave is 170volts. The peak voltage of a 120vrms square wave would have to be more than 170 volts.